# PDF File Uploaded to IPFS Does Not Display

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ipfs

***Background***

When running my app over `localhost`, I can choose my PDF file and submit it. I'm able to get the path of the IPFS file and display the path in the console.

***Problem***

When adding this line to display my file, it doesn't work and shows "No PDF file specified" instead.

`<Document src={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfshash}`} />`

`<Document file={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.docupayHash}`} />`

[image: Web page result]

***What I've Tried***

I've gone to the link in Google Chrome (`ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/"QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s"`) and I can see the file there, so I know the link is correct.

***Code***

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import web3 from "./web3";
import ipfs from "./ipfs";
import storehash from "./storehash";

import "./styles/App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contractHash: null,
    buffer: "",
    ethAddress: "",
    blockNumber: "",
    transactionHash: ""
  };
   
  captureFile = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault();

    const file = event.target.files[0];

    let reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => this.convertToBuffer(reader);
  };

  convertToBuffer = async (reader) => {
    // Convert file to buffer so that it can be uploaded to IPFS
    const buffer = await Buffer.from(reader.result);
    this.setState({buffer});
  };

  onClick = async () => {
    try {
      await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(this.state.transactionHash, (err, txReceipt) => {
        console.log(err, txReceipt);
        this.setState({txReceipt});
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Take the user's MetaMask address
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log("Sending from Metamask account: " + accounts[0]);

    // Retrieve the contract address from storehash.js
    const ethAddress= await storehash.options.address;
    this.setState({ethAddress});

    // Save document to IPFS, return its hash, and set it to state
    await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, contractHash) => {
      console.log(err, contractHash);
      this.setState({ contractHash: contractHash[0].hash });

      storehash.methods.setHash(this.state.contractHash).send({ from: accounts[0] }, (error, transactionHash) => {
        console.log(transactionHash);
        this.setState({transactionHash});
      });
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <h3> Choose file to send to IPFS </h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.captureFile} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <Document file={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.contractHash}`} />
        <a href={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.contractHash}`}>Click to download the file</a>

        <button onClick = {this.onClick}>Get Transaction Receipt</button>
        <p>IPFS Hash: {this.state.contractHash}</p>
        <p>Contract Address: {this.state.ethAddress}</p>
        <p>Tx Hash: {this.state.transactionHash}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*MyContract.sol*

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.16 <0.7.0;

contract MyContract {

  string contractHash;

  function setHash(string memory ipfsHash) public {
    contractHash = ipfsHash;
  }

  function getHash() public view returns (string memory ipfsHash) {
    return contractHash;
  }
}
```

I've looked at other solutions on SO but none that I found were particularly related to my question. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

Two things to try:

1. Add `?filename=` parameter as a hint for both gateway and `react-pdf`:

   ```html
   <Document src={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfshash}?filename=test.pdf`} />
   ```

   This will make content-type returned by the gateways more reliable and eliminate false-negatives in `react-pdf`.
2. Run your own gateway, or contact Infura and discuss raising request limits for your app.
   FYI I've run below test multiple times:

   ```
   $ curl -Ls 'https://dweb.link/ipfs/QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s?filename=test.pdf' > output && file output
   output: PDF document, version 1.5
   ```

   After a few times they stop returning PDF, instead they return HTML  page with `429 Too Many Requests` error:

   ```html
   output: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

   $ cat output
   <html>
   <head><title>429 Too Many Requests</title></head>
   <body>
   <center><h1>429 Too Many Requests</h1></center>
   <hr><center>openresty</center>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   It is very likely that `react-pdf` is unable to render your PDF because it gets `429 Too Many Requests` error response instead of the PDF payload.